# Would an existing non mobile MVC3 project benefit from upgrading to MVC4?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've two projects both are *Asp.net MVC **3*** both don't target mobile users.
One was released already, and the other is in the middle of  the development phase.

I thought of upgrading those two projects to *Asp.net MVC **4***, so I read the [New Features in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253807) section in the release notes of *Asp.net MVC 4*, it seems like there're no features that an existing Asp.net-MVC3 project cab benefit from.

All the features are related to mobile users and enhanced templates. What about speed? cache? bug fixes?

So should I upgrade my projects?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net MVC 4 added the following (non mobile related) features:

1. ASP.NET Web API
2. Default Template enhancements
3. Bundling and minifications
4. Open source libraries (Json.net and DotNetOpenAuth)
5. Separating configuration logic to (AuthConfig.cs, BundleConfig.cs) and more.
6. Add Controller everywhere in the project.

This information is from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111834846X) book which I highly recommend. So, in summary, you can benefit from upgrading to MVC4.

Comment: But for a "finished" project? will he gain a benefit from upgrading?

Comment: @ikaso The answer lists MVC 3 but it should be MVC 4.  Couldn't update as you need to change at least 6 characters....

Answer (score 1):

It's really pretty simple.  If you want to use a feature that's in MVC4, then you will need to upgrade to MVC4.

If you don't, then don't.

Are there bug-fixes?  Yes.  But if you aren't suffering from one of the bugs in MVC3, then it won't affect you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't update the released application.

We had a bigger upgrade from MVC1 to MVC4. We expected some issues, but it was much harder than we expected.

You are not asking about an upgrade from MVC1 to MVC4 but still: the issues we had were only detectable in production. There were changes in the default values for Modelbinding and we had  performance issues with routing helpers. If it is a mission critical application don't upgrade if you don't need to.

For the application under development I would allways use the latest released version of ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "finished"?  If you mean that nothing will *ever* change in this project then leave it alone.  However, odds are something will eventually change.  IMO the two primary benefits of upgrading (in this situation) are

1. Razor 2
2. Bundling and minification (as pointed out by @ikaso)

Bundling/minification do offer performance enhancements in the payload sent to the browser and help with invalidating out-dated cached css/js files.

Answer (score 0):

For an enterprise web application i see only two benefits in upgrading to MVC 4.

1. Bundling and minification come with built in support along with
   the ability to integrate custom transforms like using less for css.
2. The improved support for async/await model, which makes it a
       whole lot easier to write controller code that is a whole lot more
       scalable and less messy (You could make async controller actions in
       MVC 3 as well, but they not as intuitive or easy)

So benefits

1. -> removes loads or manual steps/ integrated build commands that were necessary to manage CSS and JS
2. -> makes it easier to build scalable apps.

P.s. one of the mobile features includes being able to write different versions of the same view, each of which is targeted to a specific browser like "windows phone os", but this could theoretically be used to target different desktop browsers as well, and also make it easier to build mobile friendly sites.